# Only Showing Part of a Site in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am building an iPad app that requires only the middle section of a web page to be visible in a UIWebView. (The entire page without the header and footer)

The portion I need to show is a form where someone enters information into and hits submit. If I position the UIWebView to only show the middle section, when I click on a text area it scrolls up / down to show the right text area on top of the iPad keyboard. This causes the header / footer to be revealed.

It doesn't seem like modifying the source code before it enters the UIWebView will work either, because the form has to work afterwards. (Like I need to be able to hit submit and have it work properly)

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a view to the top and bottom of a UIWebview so that it covers up the header and footer?

Any help would be much appreciated. I can't find a solution that will work for this situation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out -- I was able to add a view onto the UIWebView's scroll view

```
// Create new view
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,200)];

// Add to scrollView so that the added view scrolls with the UIWebView
[webView.scrollView addSubview:view];
```